# Query table 1 (sales data) using criteria in table 2 (definitions) - WHEN NO COMMON FIELDS

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to create an interactive tool in SSRS or Access where users enter definitions of promotions, then system delivers sales data relevant to those criteria.

User will choose which promotion to report and system should use associated promo definitions to deliver results.

I tried using a prompt to select promotion, then inserting the prompted value in a subquery in Access, but it doesn't like my syntax. It looked like:

```
SELECT R.NumberPresented
FROM dbo_MKT_PromoRecapMetric R
WHERE R.DonationDate = 
        (Select P.5007Start
         FROM [Promo Definitions] P
         WHERE P.PromoName = [Forms]![Promo.Select]![Promo]
        AND R.LocationCode = '5007')
```

I've been working on this for a LONG time, and any help would be much appreciated...

UPDATE: Thanks for the table join solution. I should have mentioned in my post that the date criteria is simplified. I actually will need to pick up a start and end date for the promotion to drive the date range for the query. I don't think I'd be able to do that with a join.

I think I'm looking for an equivalent of an Excel lookup in sql.

Thanks.

Comment: You include note in your question the actual error message you’re getting (though I assume it’s probably just “syntax error” with no indication of where exactly in your SQL statement the error is).

Comment: is r.LocationCode a text field or a number field? is your form Promo.Select open when the query is run?  what happens when you substitute your reference out for an actual value?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a subquery for your where statement, try joining your tables instead.

```
SELECT R.NumberPresented
FROM  dbo_MKT_PromoRecapMetric AS R  
INNER JOIN [Promo Definitions] AS P 
   ON P.[5007Start] = R.DonationDate
WHERE (((P.PromoName)=[forms]![Promo.Select]![Promo]) 
   AND ((R.LocationCode)="5007"));
```